# blade - foreach $loop->iteration

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I've problem with some loops.

I have 2 tables **Terms** [id, caption, ...] and **apps** [id, term_id, name, ...]

And in my view i want print all **apps** orderred by term_id and then by name. But i want 1 table for each **term_id** used in **apps**. and i want 1st col with correct $loop->iteration (i mean each table first row start with 1, not with +1 from previous table last row)

in controller I've passing 2 variables to my views (i have different views for each appState_id value)

```
$app = Application::where('ApplicationState_id',3)->get();
$term = Terms::all();
return view('admin.index')->with('terms', $term)
                          ->with('apps', $app);
```

in view i used foreach inside foreach / i rebuild it little bit

```
foreach terms as term
 foreach apps as app
   if $loop->first {<table><thead> ... table caption row ...}
   checking if app->term_id = term->id
      $loop->iteration, and some other stuff
   if $loop->last {</table>}
 endforeach
endforeach
```

but I want it improve little bit:

> it write table's first/caption/ row for all term even there is no record in app table
>   
>   $loop->iteration is combined per all records 
>   i want it per each table separately-i dont know can i do it

How can i pass all data from controller to be able print them seprately to corespond table?

Is there a better way how to do this? thanks for advice/hint
---edited litle bit shortened 
**Application.php**

```
class Application extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nickname',
        'comment',
        'term_id',
        'applicationstate_id',
    ];

    public function term()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Term', 'Term_id');
    }
}
```

**Term.php** - this model/table is meantime filled by me, but I want to change in future that user can add another terms of events

```
class Term extends Model
{
    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Application');
    }
}
```

I had idea that i can in controller:

> 1. check how many unique term_id is in Application table {n}
> 2. loop 1... {n}
>
>    > inside loop read data from DB for each query/each term_id and add result to an array
>
> send this array of results to view

and then try print it as {n} tables for each term_id
is this good idea how to solve this, or there is something much better?
**table applications**
[data from applications table/few records/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6RWE.png)

**ideal output on page**
[ideal output scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Oth.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:

> check how many unique term_id is in Application table {n}
>   loop 1... {n}
>
> > inside loop read data from DB for each query/each term_id and add result to an array

then I send this array of results to view

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste two models in your application

**Edit**

In your application class change the foreign key for trem

```
public function term() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Term', 'term_id');
 }
```

In your controller

```
$app = Application::with('term')->where('applicationstate_id',3)->get();  
return view('admin.index')->with('apps', $app);
```

In your admin/index.blade.php

```
@foreach($apps as $item )
      $item->trem->your attributes trem
      $item->nickname
@endforech
```

Comment: Hi, i edited my first post, Hope that can help you to understand my problem better

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: not working "Property [***] does not exist on this collection instance" for all fields i tried.

Comment: I edited again my answer, if you get errors again please review the code

Comment: Hi @user8210918, now it works w/o errors. But I stil dont know how to print 1 table for each unique term_id in view with coresponding table row index for each table. I edited first post and add some pictures of data and output i want to achieve